# How to make intertitial ad show whenever user goes to main screen?

Tags: android, android-studio, ads

So i have implemented intertitial ad in my app and i want to make it so when the user clicks back and goes to the main screen the intertitial ad to show. Right now the only time the ad shows is when the app is started.

Answer (score 0):

`onResume()` is called every time your activity is brought from the back stack, that may be the method your are looking for.